# How to remove multiple elements from a Firestore Array dynamically?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to remove multiple elements from my Firestore array:

```
var eliminatedThisRound = []

for (const player in players){
    if (players[player].eliminated === false && players[player].answer !== answer) {
        eliminatedThisRound.push(players[player].uid);
    }
}
var update = {
    roundFinished: true,
    nextRound: date.valueOf() + 12000,seconds
    players: updatedPlayers,
    remainingPlayers: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(eliminatedThisRound)
}
await t.update(gameRef, update);
```

The above returns this error:

```
transaction failure: Error: Element at index 0 is not a valid array element. Nested arrays are not supported.
```

So it would be fine if I knew the values, as I could do something like this:

```
remainingPlayers: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove("player1", "player2")
```

However I haven't found a way to make the parameter of [`arrayRemove()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/FieldValue.html#.arrayRemove) dynamic.

Any idea?

Comment: As far as I can see you should be able to pass in multiple values for `arrayRemove`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#arrayremove and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#arrayremove. What happens when you pass multiple values? Is there an error message?

Comment: Yes that's right - but my values are dynamic. I tried to pass in an array which had multiple values in it (`eliminatedThisRound` in my code above) - however it returned this error: `Element at index 0 is not a valid array element. Nested arrays are not supported. `

Comment: Ah, that error message makes sense (please include that right away in the future). The spread operator in Renaud's answer should make that error disappear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), as follows, in order to pass all elements of `eliminatedThisRound` as arguments to the `arrayRemove()` method.

```
var eliminatedThisRound = []

for (const player in players){
    if (players[player].eliminated === false && players[player].answer !== answer) {
        eliminatedThisRound.push(players[player].uid);
    }
}
var update = {

    // ...

    admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(...eliminatedThisRound)
}

await t.update(gameRef, update);
```

---

Note that you should have at least one element in the Array, otherwise you will call `arrayRemove()` with 0 argument while it requires at least 1 argument. So you may check the array length before assigning the `remainingPlayers` property to the `update` Object.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a single value or an array of values from variables like this to `arrayRemove()`:

```
var removingPlayersId = ['player1', 'player2'];
  admin
    .firestore()
    .doc('game/someID')
    .set(
      {
        remainingPlayers: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(
          removingPlayersId
        ),
      },
      { merge: true }
    );
```